# Can Solr index a directory of folders with files on my local computer?

Tags: solr

Im wondering if I can get Solr to index a directory on my local computer that contains many folders containing the files I want indexed. Also, could I exclude some file types as well?

Comment: this question is a bit to vague as-is. The answer to both questions is "yes, Solr can do that" but that probably won't help you. It might be better if you indicate what you have tried and is not working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the command I ran that worked:
`java -Dc=myCollection -Drecursive -Dauto -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar c:/folder1/folder2`